# admin: override the "save" action

Tags: python, django

This is about the `admin` part of django. There are three models in `models.py` file:

```
class In(models.model):
    id = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("id"),max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("number"))

class Storage(models.model):
    id = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("id"),max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("number"))

class Out(models.model):
    id = models.CharField(verbose_name=_("id"),max_length=20,primary_key=True)
    num = models.IntegerField(verbose_name=("number"))
```

I've already registered them in the `admin.py` file:

```
admin.site.register(In)
admin.site.register(Storage)
admin.site.register(Out)
```

I hope that:

1. when a user clicks `save` or `save and add another` or `save and continue editing` in the `In` form, django will not only save the form data in the `In` class, but also save the data in the `Storage` class.
2. When a user clicks `save` or `save and add another` or `save and continue editing` in the `Out` form, django will not only save the form data in the `Out` class, but also look for the same id in the `Storage` class, and substract `num` in `Out` from `num` in `Storage` for the same id.

For example, in the `In` form, the user inputs data `id=1, num=3`, and `save`, the data will store in both `In` and `Storage`, then in the `Out` form, the user inputs data `id=1, num=1`, and `save`, the data will store in `Out`, and data in the `Storage` class will become `id=1, num=2`.

How to do the trick?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`post_save()` signal](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/signals/#post-save) is a good fit for what you are trying to achieve. They will be triggered every time an object is saved. Hook them up in `In` and `Out` and update your `Storage` as needed.